# PHP not parsing wordpress rss feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have read about a dozen posts on this topic here on SO and all of them refer to the whitespace issue, which I don't have, and feed validator agrees my feed is okay (http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgearmunk.com%2Fblog%2Ffeed%2F)

I am using the following code to parse the rss:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http:/gearmunk.com/blog/feed/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array ( 
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
);
array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 3;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
$title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
$link = $feed[$x]['link'];
$description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
$date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
?>
```

but if you look at http://gearmunk.com/index3.php you will see, on the right, it lists 3 bad dates and no rss data. If I put in another feed URL it works fine, and if I put my rss feed into Google reader it works just fine. I'm hoping there is something stupid simple I'm missing. Can someone help?

thanks,
Erik

MORE INFORMATION:

I started to focus in on it being a wordpress problem, so I tried some other wordpress RSS feeds. One from CNN works fine (http://religion.blogs.cnn.com/feed/), however, one from BoingBoing (also a WP site) doesn't work: http://boingboing.net/feed.

I am not getting the XML Parse error normally associated with the whitespace issue, so I don't think that is it.

Erik

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
$rss->load('http:/gearmunk.com/blog/feed/');
```

To the following ( note the extra / )

```
$rss->load('http://gearmunk.com/blog/feed/');
```

Code appeared to run as expected with that change.

Comment: Conrad, I did change that and I still get the same problem:

    <?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://gearmunk.com/blog/feed/');
    $feed = array();

http://gearmunk.com/index3.php

Comment: Please try again, that's the only change I made, and I get what appears to be expected output. I've copied the code with just that one change to http://dev.rcs.us/stackoverflow.com/14390011/

Comment: Conrad. Very interesting. It works on your server but not on mine (the same server hosting the WP blog). I confirmed (more than once) that http:// is in there. We now can safely say it is something on my server causing the problem. I will keep digging, thanks so much!

Comment: I even created a new file to make sure it wasn't other php messing with it, same result. (http://gearmunk.com/feedy.php)

Comment: Hey Conrad, quick question (a little off topic). if you check out http://gearmunk.com/feedy.php now I have error reporting turned on. It says the url http://gearmunk.com/blog/feed/ is a 404 (when it clearly exists). any idea what would cause this?

Comment: It might be worth contacting your hosting provider. It might an issue with the lookup of DNS on a record within their environment.  If you have full access to the server, a modification to /etc/resolve.conf would likely resolve that, if it were in fact the case.

Comment: Conrad - I literally just figured this out 15 minutes before reading your post. I have been chasing a load() problem or a allow_url_fopen problem for a couple of days. As expected, in a properly setup environment, local domains shouldn't hit DNS (it's unneeded overhead). However, hitting the IP directly didn't work either, and that is because of a bad PTR record left over from a previous domain. It's a Dedicated VM so there is no real hosting support. I just fixed DNS and it works fine. Thanks tons for all of your help and feedback.

Comment: Thanks @conrad10781. This was my issue as well. The modification to the /etc/resolve.conf worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I came across it trying to fix my own WordPress RSS feed issue.  In my case I was missing the PHP XML extension.

So I ran
`apt-get install php7.0-xml` (I'm running PHP v7.0 on Ubuntu, check your php version), restarted my server and it totally fixed my problem!

For CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat on PHP 7:

```
yum install php70w-xml
```

Hope this helps somebody!